# Maintain Version Information in one central place with autotools

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I use the gnu autools (autoconf, automake, libtool) to build a shared library and  an associated binary, and a texinfo documentation.

In configure.ac, there is a version information maintained.

Now in the texinfo sources for example, I want to include the current version.

```
 @set VERSION 0.0.1
 @set UPDATED 18 June 2018
```

I would like to define versions only once and reuse them throughout the code base where applicable, so when bundling a release I don't end up having for example a pdf with the wrong version. Is there an established pattern for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to define versions only once and reuse them throughout
>   the code base where applicable, so when bundling a release I don't end
>   up having for example a pdf with the wrong version. Is there an
>   established pattern for this?

Sure.  As you already observe, `configure.ac` contains version information, which in fact one generally specifies at the very top, as an argument to the `AC_INIT` macro.  The primary function of the `configure` script built from it is to construct other files used in the build by filling in template files with known or discovered values.  The most common files prepared that way are Makefiles, but Autotools `configure` scripts are in no way specific to those.  In just the same way, they can prepare headers, documentation files, and pretty much any other file that can be handled as text.

For example, if you wanted to automatically encode a build or version number into your sources then you might do so by managing a header file containing that information.

To make that work, you simply name the file to be built in the argument to an `AC_CONFIG_FILES` macro (you may use several if you wish):

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/version.h])
```

Be default, `configure` will expect the template for that output file to be named by adding the suffix `.in` (*i.e.* `src/version.h.in`).  Within, reference Autoconf output variables by name, bounded by '@' characters: `@VERSION@`.  When `configure` runs (or actually when the generated script `config.status` runs) it will create the specified output file by copying the template, substituting output variable references with discovered output variable values.

Since many cases where you want to populate version information will be similar in that the configurable part is a very small proportion of the overall file, it is often convenient to leverage features such as Texinfo's `@include` to isolate the configurable portions in small, separate files.  The header example demonstrates this.

For texinfo in particular, however, Automake includes [a special provision](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Texinfo.html#index-Texinfo-flag_002c-VERSION) along these lines for version information in texinfo sources.  If you name a .texi source file in a TEXINFO primary, and that file `@include`s one whose name matches the glob `vers*.texi`, then Automake will arrange for that included file to be automatically generated (unless you put in your own rules for building it).  In the specific case of texinfo versioning, then, making use of that facility for generating and incorporating version data is preferable to rolling your own version file generation.

Comment: thank you for the answer. If I may ask a follow-up question. While putting this into my source tree, I realized that there was a `stamp-vti` file generated by the toolchain, that contains texinfo definitions of the variables `VERSION` and UPDATED just as I needed. Is it common to just use this?

Comment: @wirrbel, I was using texinfo as an example of a more general principle, and in the process I happened to stomp around in an area that would be better supported in a slightly different way.  I have updated my answer to use a different general example, and to describe a related special provision the Autotools make for the special case of version information in texinfo files.  To answer your question, no, it is not common or even appropriate to rely directly on `stamp-vti`, but Automake has a similarly easy alternative for you.